# Mamp php code to run a script on linux cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, mamp

I have installed MAMP and have my php scripts that execute a shell script and Rscript on my mac. Now, If I need to run the same on linux cluster, how do I proceed?

I have a html page that helps me choose some options and run the shell script.

I would need the same html page but the shell script to run on a linux cluster instead of my mac. Any help would be appreciated as I am really struck.